# How to use the didTapMessageBubbleAtIndexPath function of the JSQMessageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I want to create a chat in which when I tap the message Bubble , Its speaks out the text part of the JSQMessage

The code I used is as under:

```
public func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView, didTapMessageBubbleAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


    let speechUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: messages[indexPath.item].text)

    speechSynthesizer.speak(speechUtterance)


}
```

The problem I am facing is that the function doesnot get called when I tap the bubble.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
let synth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
var myUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "")

public func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView, didTapMessageBubbleAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

      // Make sure you are actually getting the text in messages[indexPath.item].text

      myUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: messages[indexPath.item].text)
      myUtterance.rate = 0.3
      synth.speakUtterance(myUtterance)
}
```

Now, for your issue please check you might not be writing `cellForItemAtIndexPath` . This will prevent `didTapMessageBubbleAtIndexPath` to call.

Comment: The problem was actually in the message content itself. The text was in Hindi but I never really set the voice of SpeechUtterance to hindi which has now done the job. How can I make it dynamic as for the Synthesizer to autodetect the text language and produce speech accordingly?